# low latency data link pc to android

Tags: android, low-latency

can anyone recommend a method for low latency bi-directional com link between my pc app and android slave app. the app i have works now via wifi but the latency is too slow (about 300mS), i'm looking to get it down to 10mS or so.

the android is acting like a glorified remote control to the game on the pc. the apk displays a low res image and sends button presses back to the game and the round trip need to be quick

i'm thinking the only option beside the network, is to connect a usb cable but i don't see a lot of support for that path and not even sure it would be lower latency than wifi

any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

USB would have much lower latency, and there's plenty of USB support in Android.  Check out http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/accessory.html  Bluetooth may also be an option, but I'm not sure if it will get you to the latency you want-  USB can.